# ¿Cómo borrar datos basura de una matriz?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué salen tantos datos cuando solo debería ser 1,2,3?, solo intento crear una matriz básica que en cada columna pueda imprimir un único dato hasta que termine la fila, pero no se que pasa en C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matriz[3][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        matriz[0][1] = 1;
        matriz[0][2] = 2;
        matriz[0][3] = 3;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << matriz[i][0] << endl;
        cout << matriz[i][2] << endl;
        cout << matriz[i][3] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: tengo la misma duda, pero parece que nadie entiende

Comment: a como se ponga la matriz muestra archivos basura

Comment: @EstherPorta No es que no se entienda, es que el código de ambos tiene un error tan básico que es difícil explicar el motivo, es como tratar de explicar porque una multiplicación falla a una persona que no sabe sumar.

Comment: En el primer for usa tu índice `matriz[i][0] = 1;` e inicializa la matriz así `int matriz[3][3];`, saludos

Comment: Solo inicializas el índice 0 de la matriz, por lo tanto, los índices 1 y 2 toma lo que encuentre en memoria, es decir, matriz[1][0], matriz[1,1], etc no están inicializados a 0 y por eso te muestra cualquier cosa que en ese momento se encuentre en memoria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando haces `int array[N]` N es el tamaño o largo del array. Un array se puede recorrer por sus índices. Los índices del array van desde cero a N-1.

**¿Por qué N-1?**

Porque se empieza a contar desde el cero, por ejemplo la cantidad de números que hay desde el 0 al 9 son Diez (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int matriz[3][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        matriz[0][1] = 1; // debería ser matriz[i][0] = 1;
        matriz[0][2] = 2; // debería ser matriz[i][1] = 2;
        matriz[0][3] = 3; // Esto no debería estar el indice maximos es N-1-> 2-1=1, es decir tienes solo los índices cero y uno
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << matriz[i][0] << endl;
        cout << matriz[i][2] << endl; //deberia ser cout << matriz[i][1] << endl;
        cout << matriz[i][3] << endl; //no debería estar presente
    }
}
```

Es decir:

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[3][2]={};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        matriz[i][0] = 1;
        matriz[i][1] = 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << matriz[i][0] << endl;
        cout << matriz[i][1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dada la siguiente matriz:

| jaula | perros | gatos | gallos | leones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jaula1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| jaula2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| jaula3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Las filas son, jaula1, jaula2, jaula3.
Las columnas son, perros, gatos, gallos, leones.
Tiene 3 filas y 4 columnas.

La presentamos en código:

```
              filas
              |
int miMatriz[ 3 ][ 4 ];
                   |
                   columnas
```

Le cargamos los animales de compañía (¿?) dentro, iterando sobre las columnas.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++)
{
    matriz[ i ][ 0 ] = i  + 1;
    matriz[ i ][ 2 ] = cantidadColumnas - i;
    matriz[ i ][ 3 ] = 1;
      // en la primer iteración, asignamos un valor a cada fila de
      // la columna **perros**, y luego seguimos con la segunda, etc.
}
```

Cabe recordar, como marcan otras respuesta y comentarios, que 4 filas (o columnas) se traduce a código como:

```
fila[ 0 ]
fila[ 1 ]
fila[ 2 ]
fila[ 3 ]
```

si intentamos usar fila[ 4 ], obtendremos un error.

Es una explicación muy básica (tal vez demasiado), pero prefiero pecar de excesivo a que queden dudas.